# How to avoid simultaneous mutable and immutable borrowing in Rust?

Tags: rust

I`m writing a function which iterates over all edges of a mesh and splits long ones. But getting a compilation error while trying to borrow a mesh struct as mutable and immutable simultaneously. Does anyone have an idea how to avoid mutable and immutable borrowing at the same time here?

```
fn split_edges(&self, mesh: &'a mut TMesh, max_edge_length: TMesh::ScalarType) {
    let edges: Vec<TMesh::EdgeDescriptor> = mesh.edges().collect();

    for edge in edges {
        let edge_length = mesh.edge_length(edge);

        // Split long edges at the middle
        if edge_length > max_edge_length {
            let (v1, v2) = mesh.edge_positions(edge);
            let split_at = v1 + (v2 - v1).scale(cast(0.5).unwrap());
            mesh.split_edge(edge, &split_at);
        }
    }
}
```

Compilation error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*mesh` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src\remeshing\incremental.rs:48:17
   |
12 | impl<'a, TMesh: EditableMesh<'a>> IncrementalRemesher<'a, TMesh> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
39 |         let edges: Vec<TMesh::EdgeDescriptor> = mesh.edges().collect();
   |                                                 ------------
   |                                                 |
   |                                                 immutable borrow occurs here
   |                                                 argument requires that `*mesh` is borrowed for `'a`
...
48 |                 mesh.split_edge(edge, &split_at);
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

Traits:

```
pub trait Mesh<'a> {
    type ScalarType: Floating;

    type EdgeDescriptor: Clone + Copy;
    type VertexDescriptor: Clone + Copy;
    type FaceDescriptor: Clone + Copy;

    type FacesIter: Iterator<Item = Self::FaceDescriptor>;
    type VerticesIter: Iterator<Item = Self::VertexDescriptor>;
    type EdgesIter: Iterator<Item = Self::EdgeDescriptor>;

    /// Creates mesh from vertices and face indices
    fn from_vertices_and_indices(vertices: &Vec<Point3<Self::ScalarType>>, faces: &Vec<usize>) -> Self;

    /// Iterator over mesh faces
    fn faces(&'a self) -> Self::FacesIter;
    /// Iterator over mesh vertices
    fn vertices(&'a self) -> Self::VerticesIter;
    /// Iterator over mesh edges
    fn edges(&'a self) -> Self::EdgesIter;

    /// Returns positions of face vertices in ccw order
    fn face_positions(&self, face: Self::FaceDescriptor) -> (Point3<Self::ScalarType>, Point3<Self::ScalarType>, Point3<Self::ScalarType>);
    /// Returns face normal
    fn face_normal(&self, face: Self::FaceDescriptor) -> UnitVector3<Self::ScalarType>;

    /// Returns edge length
    fn edge_positions(&self, edge: Self::EdgeDescriptor) -> (Point3<Self::ScalarType>, Point3<Self::ScalarType>);
    /// Returns edge length
    fn edge_length(&self, edge: Self::EdgeDescriptor) -> Self::ScalarType;
}

///
/// Triangular mesh that supports editing operations
/// 
pub trait EditableMesh<'a>: Mesh<'a> {
    fn collapse_edge(&mut self, edge: Self::EdgeDescriptor);
    fn is_edge_collapse_safe(&mut self, edge: Self::EdgeDescriptor) -> bool;

    fn flip_edge(&mut self, edge: Self::EdgeDescriptor);
    fn is_edge_flip_safe(&mut self, edge: Self::EdgeDescriptor) -> bool;

    fn split_edge(&mut self, edge: Self::EdgeDescriptor, at: &Point3<Self::ScalarType>);
    fn shift_vertex(&mut self, vertex: Self::VertexDescriptor, to: &Point3<Self::ScalarType>);
}
```

Comment: This is a little hard to parse without any of the function signatures. Could you provide the signatures of `mesh.edges` and `mesh.split_edge`?

Comment: Actually, looking at the error, can you try to change the signature of `split_edges` to `fn split_edges<'m>(&self, mesh: &'m mut TMesh, max_edge_length: TMesh::ScalarType)`. Note the changed lifetime annotation for `mesh`.

Comment: The error makes sense to me. How will the loop continue after the contents of range that is looped over is changed? I assume `mesh.split_edge` changes the contents of mesh.

Comment: A general piece of advice: When a struct is generic over some lifetime `'a`, very rarely do you want that to be the lifetime of a `&self` receiver. That means that when you call something like `my_mesh.edges()` the returned iterator captures the lifetime of the struct when really you only want it to capture the lifetime of the borrow. All those methods that take `&'a self` should probably be generic over some lifetime `'s` and take `&'s self` instead.

Comment: @ÖzgürMuratSağdıçoğlu `edges` contains indices of edges inside of internal storage in Mesh. `mesh.split_edge` only inserts new elements to it so old indices remain valid.

Comment: @isaactfa Iterator returned by `edges()` is an associate type which requires a lifetime param. Right now I'm passing Mesh lifetime to it which will conflict with `edges<'s>` lifetime.


`type FacesIter = CornerTableFacesIter<'a, TCorner, TVertex>;
    type VerticesIter = CornerTableVerticesIter<'a, TCorner, TVertex>;
    type EdgesIter = CornerTableEdgesIter<'a, TCorner, TVertex>;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @isactfa stated in the comment I had to change the iterator lifetime to lifetime of borrow.

```
type FacesIter<'iter>: Iterator<Item = Self::FaceDescriptor> where Self: 'iter;
type VerticesIter<'iter>: Iterator<Item = Self::VertexDescriptor> where Self: 'iter;
type EdgesIter<'iter>: Iterator<Item = Self::EdgeDescriptor> where Self: 'iter;

/// Iterator over mesh faces
fn faces<'a>(&'a self) -> Self::FacesIter<'a>;
/// Iterator over mesh vertices
fn vertices<'a>(&'a self) -> Self::VerticesIter<'a>;
/// Iterator over mesh edges
fn edges<'a>(&'a self) -> Self::EdgesIter<'a>;
```